# Will User GPO settings apply to a Computer OU

Tags: group-policy

If I have a GPO that contains a handful of user settings - if i apply this to a OU container which contains computer objects - will those User Policies then apply to any user who logs onto that Computer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, no this will not happen. Fortunately, [Group Policy Loopback Processing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231287) can be enabled, which will do exactly what you're looking for.